# Cisco 1841 banner info

Tags: cisco, radius

I am using a Cisco 1841 router. I have programmed radius settings onto it which is always used to login if the radius server is present. If the radius server is down or not present it then converts to the line con 0 password. Is there a way to display a banner messages when it falls back to the line con 0 password. 
Right now if radius fails it will just ask for password. I would like it to display a message before that password prompt to alert users that line con 0 password is now required

Thanks
Robert

Answer (score 1):

I don't think that there is anything to do this out of the box. But if you run a recent IOS version you may be able to do this with the [Event Manager](http://www.cisco.com/en/US/products/ps6815/products_ios_protocol_group_home.html).

Something like

```
event manager applet CHANGE_BANNER
 event syslog pattern ...
 action 1 cli banner motd ...
```

This can trigger a CLI action when a syslog message is generated by the router.
Of course you need to get a syslog entry when the radius server is no longer responding, I'm not sure of how to get that. I guess running "debug radius elog" can generate this.

Another way would be to use `event track` instead of `event syslog`. Event track can trigger action depending of the result of an IP SLA monitor but it needs a very recent IOS version and with IP SLA monitor you will be able to check your radius server with a ping but not to test the radius service itself, so it's not very reliable.